# Hiding Tabs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am re-designing the purchase ordering system for my company. I want to make the process near fully automated and have it live in one place. I have not had much trouble apart from the bit where my suppliers need to edit their tab by entering quotes (prices).

The problem is that they can see other suppliers (competitors) tabs and I do not want this to happen.

So, I am an intermediate on apps script so can find my way around and have a small scale script that does work at the moment but as I increase the scale I worry that my code will have problems.

The script below checks the effective user and hides a tab depending on the email address of the user. This is all well and good but on a larger scale where each supplier (out of 5) must not be able to see the other 4 seller tabs, this will present a problem.

```
function validUsers() {
  var adminUsers = ['supplier1@email.com'];
  var Users = ['supplier2@email.com'];

  if (adminUsers.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Seller1").showSheet()
  }

  if (Users.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Seller1").hideSheet()
  }
}
```

Basically, is there a straight forward way or better way than I am doing? 
All I want is to hide 4 our of 5 seller tabs depending on which seller is editing the sheet. So, Seller1 only sees the Seller1 tab where there are actually 5 Seller tabs.

Comment: This is not really something spreadsheets are designed to do. Consider creating a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) where each user has their own front end without ever directly seeing the spreadsheet if you want to keep your current infrastructure.

Comment: So, I could build out a menu system which shows each user their own instance of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including all the sellers in a single spreadsheet, have you considered creating a spreadsheet file for each seller which they have access to?  Then use the [importrange()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) function to import each into your central spreadsheet.  This minimizes the need for code, but does mean that all changes to the Supplier's information needs to happen in the associated file.  You can still have additional columns with formulas for internal calculations inside the central spreadsheet.

Karl

Answer (score 0):

Thank you got the suggestion. I have considered this as an alternative or a form for suppliers to fill in but I have solved the issue.

I now have all but a welcome tab hidden at first. once the document is opened a prompt box appears asking for a password. Depending on the password given, a certain tab(s) will show. This allows them to make their changes, my staff to access everything and keeps suppliers from seeing each others quotes.

Regards,

James